# Run a Java jar from another folder, but keep files in original folder

Tags: java, javafx

So currently right now in my Java program I have it so it can correctly start another jar file. But the jar file is not creating the files in its directory but instead creating the files in my programs directory. Is there any way I can make it so the files will be created in the directory of the original file?

Comment: You need to come to grips with the concept of "working directory".  This is the current directory from which the program is executed (ie `"."`), which may be different from the directory in which the Jar is stored.  This is a common way of executing programs. To answer you question, no, there is no "easy" way to achieve what you are describing. Instead, most OSes have a concept of "common/application file storage".  This a a location where applications may store data.  Common it's somewhere linked to the user's home directory

Comment: Is there a good reason to use a jar simply to start another jar? Why not just create a shortcut to the jar to open it?

Comment: I agree with @Sedrick here: if you have one application starting another application it seems pretty likely (not certain, but likely) that you are using the wrong solution for whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Well I was trying to make a dashboard of sorts. So it would download a jar from a site to a folder then run that jar inside the program.

Comment: As your working directory is from where you are invoking the jar, I guess you can give the file's path while creating in 2nd jar relative to the first jar.